# get inReplyTo and references from Thunderbird mail header

Tags: javascript, xpcom, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am banging my head: how do I get In-Reply-To and the References from a Thunderbird message header? Is it a message header property: aMsgHdr.get (String??)Property()?

Where do I find possible property names?
If it is not in the db, how do I get it out of the header?
And how can I set it?

many thanks for help,
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

it is not in the header. one needs to look at the mimemessage. I put it to MDN in the hotow's how to do it (bottom of page). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Message_View_Examples#section_8

Some header entries are available in msgHdr, some are not. Those can be found in the mimemessage returned by the callback in MsgHdrToMimeMessage . They can be retrieved by aMimeMsg.get('in-reply-to') or aMimeMsg.headers['in-reply-to'][0] (if, for example, the in-reply-to header is required - note the [0] if aMimeMsg.headers is used).